# How to perform a Differential Sync between a collection of objects and a DB Table

Tags: java, hibernate, synchronization

I have a Hashmap of Type (String, PojoObj). This is used by my Java program which is running and triggered using Quartz schedular at regular intervals.

For safety during abrupt killing of the java process.. the Hashmap will be destroyed.. making loss of data..

so, i am planning to dump/Sync the Hashmap data ( the pojo objects ) when the class is started executing by the schedular. it will be effective if the sync is differential.. ( only changed values are updated in DB ).

I dont have any idea to do it... Please help me.. I am using Hibernate 3.5 in my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ShutDown Handler for this purpose :

```
public final class MyShutDownHandler extends Thread {

    private List<IObserver> observerList;
    private static MyShutDownHandler shutdownHandler;

    private MyShutDownHandler() {
        observerList = new ArrayList<IObserver>();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(this);
    }

    public static MyShutDownHandler getShutdownHandler() {
        if (shutdownHandler == null) {
            synchronized (MyShutDownHandler.class) {
                if (shutdownHandler == null) {
                    shutdownHandler = new MyShutDownHandler();
                }
            }
        }
        return shutdownHandler;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (IObserver observer : observerList) {
            observer.execute();
        }
    }

    public void register(IObserver observer) {
        observerList.add(observer);
    }
}
```

You can register as many Observers (implementations of IObserver) as you need. A Particular Observer can do the necessary
processes before a shutdown happens.

```
public interface IObserver {

    void execute();

}
```

Comment: This only used when we perform a proper shutdown of the application or user indused shut down... but i need a periodical sync between the Hashmap Pojos to the DB2 tables.... hows its possible? and that too a differential one...

Comment: may be i can use hibernate to save the pojo objects by iterating the Hashmap.. But the challenge is the Sync should be a differential one... to overcome the delay in performing the truncating of existing rows and dumping all the records again...